# What is the electrical conductivity (S/m) of a carbon nanotube?

Tags: nanoscience

I have been searching around for a while for this but I am having trouble finding any actual figures, all I can seem to find is that it is "very high".

So I am wondering, does anyone have any figures of what the electrical conductivity of a carbon nanotube is, a theoretical or estimated answer is fine. I am preferably looking for the answer in $Sm^{-1}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers will greatly vary depending on the kind of nanotube. The following are some examples from cursory Google searches.

> Electrical conductivity was increased by 50 percent to 1,230 siemens
>   per meter.

http://news.ncsu.edu/releases/wms-zhu-cnt-composites/

> And that’s not all: colossal carbon tubes are ductile and can be
>   stretched, which makes them attractive for applications requiring high
>   toughness. They also have high electrical conductivities of around 103
>   siemens per centimetre at room temperature, compared with 102 siemens
>   per centimetre for multi-walled carbon nanotube fibres.

http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2008/aug/08/carbon-nanotubes-but-without-the-nano

> The researchers found that the electrical conductivity increased with
>   increasing nanotube content and temperature – in contrast to earlier
>   findings. They observed a maximum conductivity of 3375 siemens per
>   metre at 77°C in samples that were 15% nanotube by volume.

http://physicsworld.com/cws/article/news/2003/aug/20/nanotubes-boost-ceramic-performance

Answer (score 1):

The conductivity of a nanotube depends on the chirality / diameter of the individual nanotube and the conductivity. The chirality determines whether a nanotube is classified as either metallic or semiconducting.

The highest conductivity that has been measured for a carbon nanotube is ~100 MS/m, which is equivalent to a resistivity of 1 uOhm-cm. This result was reported by McCuen and Park (2004) for a metallic carbon nanotube.

https://doi.org/10.1557/mrs2004.79